# Container with Image & Image Description to be Responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create this simple landing page where there is one row, which contains two `<div class="image">`, which are container div's which hold the image, the image title, and the image description.

I am trying to get it to be responsive so that when a user on mobile device access the page, the two images will be on one column as opposed to one row. I have started over and over adjusting CSS trying to get what I want, and the closest I have gotten is the example provided in the below snippet.

CSS Stylings I have tried but failed:

- `@media (min-width: ){}` to change max/min size when the screen goes above/below certain pixels
- Set a minimum size for the image itself
- Tried the same for the container of the image

I couldn't get any of the above to make my landing page responsive.

```css
.container1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 160px;
  margin-right: 180px;
}

.container1 p {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: -10px;
}

.container1 h3 {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0;
}

.armycontracts {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.armycontracts h3 {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.usmccontracts h3 {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.usmccontracts {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.landinghead {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.projectInfo {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

#contentRow {
  margin-top: -50px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.ms-core-pageTitle {
  display: none;
}

.row-one {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .row-one {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}

.image {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: auto;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  padding: 20px;
  height: auto;
}

.image__img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.image__overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.25s;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.image__overlay>* {
  transform: translateY(20px);
  transition: transform 0.25s;
}

.image__overlay:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.image__overlay:hover>* {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.image__title {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.image__description {
  font-size: 1.25em;
  margin-top: 0.25em;
}

#contentRow {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#sideNavBox {
  DISPLAY: none
}

#contentBox {
  margin-left: 0px
}

#particles-js {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-image: url("");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Projects Landing Page</title>
</head>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
<div id="particles-js"></div>

<body>
  <h3 class="landinghead">Projects Landing Page</h3>
  <p class="projectInfo">Here you will find a collection of Active/Ongoing Projects</p>
  <div class="row-one">
    <div class="image">
      <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">
        <img class="image__img" src="https://api.army.mil/e2/c/images/2021/01/26/4c5cde5d/max1200.jpg" alt="Army" />
        <div class="image__overlay">
          <div class="image__title">Team 1 Contracts</div>
          <p class="image__description">
            - Contr. 1 <br>
            - Contr. 2 <br>
            - Contr. 3 <br>
          </p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">
        <img class="image__img" src="https://media.defense.gov/2021/Feb/01/2002574582/-1/-1/0/210124-M-WH885-1032.JPG" alt="Usmc" />
        <div class="image__overlay">
          <div class="image__title">Team 2 Contracts</div>
          <p class="image__description">
            - Contr. 1 <br>
            - Contr. 2 <br>
            - Contr. 3
          </p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried making div.row-one a flex with max-width: xyz px for each div.image ? If you make div.row-one a flex, and put flex-wrap:wrap. It will automatically wrap the second image below it once the screen is small enough.

Comment: @nimishcodes I tried that here https://jsfiddle.net/o32w7j4a/1/ and shrinks the row

Comment: You have not made the .row-one a flex. There is a container that is flex, but it is not being used in HTML

Comment: @nimishcodes sorry check here https://jsfiddle.net/o32w7j4a/2/

Comment: You are missing min-width in img. Check out the answer below. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.row-one{
width: 80%;
text-align: center;
padding: 20px;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}

.image{
flex: 1 45%;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
max-width: 400px;
min-width: 200px;
margin-left: 40px;
margin-right: 40px;
padding: 20px;
height: auto;
}
```

This works. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n1f0odgy/9/)

Comment: That does work, I just selected another image with the same exact size for reference (both 1200x800) but they are showing as different heights/size still?

Comment: Did you delete your JSfiddle comment? I was looking at it. Apparently, they are different sizes.

Comment: In regards to my previous comment, https://jsfiddle.net/6bsqcgLm/ they are not centered aswell

Comment: Remove 80% width from div.row-one to fix that.

Comment: Instead of using <br> tags in your <p> for overlay, I would suggest you use display-flex in overlay and flex-direction: column to achieve that. You can use justify-content: space-between. This is better way than <br> since they can essentially cause unresponsive behavior.

Comment: I tried implementing into my actual webpage and the results are not similar to that of the fiddle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229059/discussion-between-nimishcodes-and-bigchungus).

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'flex-direction' to achieve what you want.
This page has pretty good information about it.
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-direction/

Apply a flex-direction to your 'row-image' class. Set it to 'column' when you want your elements to stack, set it to 'row' when the elements should flow in a line.